# Spring XD distributed mode redis configuration

Tags: redis, spring-xd, redis-sentinel

I am trying to configure spring XD in distributed mode and I unfortunately I was unable to do so.
I am trying to back the inter-module channels using redis and I have a 3 node redis 3.0 cluster running.

My changes to the configuration are shown below, please let me know if I am missing out anything or do I need to do any thing else to make my spring instance run in distributed mode:

servers.yml file of xd-container is configured like

```
            spring:
              profiles: container
            xd:
              transport: redis
            embeddedHsql: false
            .
            .
            .
            .
            spring:
              datasource:
                url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-instance01:3306/springxd
                username: springxd
                password: springxd
                driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                validationQuery: select 1
            .
            .
            .
            spring:
              redis:
               port: 6379
               host: redis-instance01
               pool:
                 maxIdle: 8
                 minIdle: 0
                 maxActive: -1
                 maxWait: 30000
               sentinel:
                 master: mymaster
                 nodes: redis-instance02:6379,redis-instance03:6379
```

If I run the xd-container with this configuration I get the error stack trace as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/kbeathanabhotla/779f4e05a4a8de347dbed26d7fd6686a#file-redis-spring-xd-with-sentenel-txt)

And If I remove sentinel, sentinel:master, sentinel:nodes, the container is starting fine but failing when some stream is deployed, the error log is as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/kbeathanabhotla/50a1690b0fd672549f619ef7a6d0e0cd#file-springxd-redis-without-sentinel-txt)

**But there is absolutely no problem with my redis cluster when trying to connect from java using JedisCluster.**

Am I missing something in this configuration?
Any thoughts or comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

increase Redis maxclients

My test app works(distributed mode with 3 containers) with confgiuration (one machine):

```
spring:
  profiles: container
xd:
  transport: redis
---
# Redis properties
spring:
  redis:
    port: 6379
    host: 127.0.0.1
    pool:
      maxIdle: 8
      minIdle: 0
      maxActive: -1
      maxWait: 30000
```

---

Redis is mostly single threaded application.

Redis will attempt to persist the data to disk. While redis forks for this process, it still slows everything down.

For distributed mode - need use kafka, for example.

Hope this helps you.